# How do I add scroll function to main window in python pyqt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to learn pyqt5 in python by creating a small application. For one of the windows, I need to add a vertical scroll bar to the window. Now, this window has a table made using QLabel and QLineEdit. Check the picture to get exactly how it looks like.[image: Table-Picture]

As you can see there are a lot of chemicals, which goes below the window screen. I have tried numerous approaches but somehow couldn't get the result. If I am able to get the scroll, all the elements get aligned one under another (QVBoxLayout) which is not the way I want the elements to be aligned.

Here's the code I'm using

```
class ChemicalWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,chemicals,data):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setWindowTitle("Chemicals")
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600,600))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:#eaf4f4;")
        self.chemicals = chemicals
        self.data = data

        self.createBody()
        self.createButtons()

    def createBody(self):

        headerLabel = QLabel('Chemicals',scroll_widget)
        headerLabel.move(265,10)
        headerLabel.resize(70,40)
        headerLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#000;")

        tcLabel = QLabel('Tc',scroll_widget)
        tcLabel.move(200,50)
        tcLabel.resize(60,30)
        tcLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#000;")

        pcLabel = QLabel('Pc',scroll_widget)
        pcLabel.move(280,50)
        pcLabel.resize(60,30)
        pcLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#000;")

        cpLabel = QLabel('Cp',scroll_widget)
        cpLabel.move(360,50)
        cpLabel.resize(60,30)
        cpLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#000;")

        self.chemical_names = self.chemicals.keys()

        y_position = 90

        # List for keeping chemical inputs variables in form of dict of list -> {A:[chemical_a_tc,chemical_a_pc,chemical_a_cp],
        #                                                                        B:[chemical_b_tc,chemical_b_pc,...],...}
        self.chemical_inputs = dict()

        # Creating labels for the chemical names
        for name in self.chemical_names:
            chemicalLabel = QLabel(name,scroll_widget)
            chemicalLabel.move(70,y_position)
            chemicalLabel.resize(75,30)
            chemicalLabel.setStyleSheet("color:#000;")
            chemicalLabel.setToolTip(name)
            y_position += 40

            current_chemical_inputs = dict()
            for chemical_input in self.chemicals[name]:
                current_chemical_inputs[chemical_input] = QLineEdit(scroll_widget) 
            self.chemical_inputs[name] = current_chemical_inputs

        position_y = 90
        for individual_chemical in self.chemical_inputs:
            position_x = 160
            for chemical_input in self.chemical_inputs[individual_chemical]:
                self.chemical_inputs[individual_chemical][chemical_input].setText(str(self.data['chemicals'][individual_chemical][chemical_input]))
                self.chemical_inputs[individual_chemical][chemical_input].move(position_x,position_y)
                self.chemical_inputs[individual_chemical][chemical_input].resize(80,30)
                self.chemical_inputs[individual_chemical][chemical_input].setStyleSheet("color:#000;background-color:#a9d6e5;padding:2px;")
                
                position_x += 90                
            position_y += 40

    def createButtons(self):
        close_button = QPushButton('Close',self)
        close_button.move(510,550)
        close_button.resize(70,30)
        close_button.setStyleSheet("background-color:#00509d;color:#fff;")
        close_button.clicked.connect(self.closeButton)

    def closeButton(self):
        self.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. use QScrollArea; 2. use QGridLayout, or nested layouts (multiple QHBoxLayout added to the main QVBoxLayout), set for a container QWidget that you'll add to QScrollArea. Remember to use `setWidgetResizable(True)`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it using a combination of QHBoxLayout as columns and QVBoxLayout as rows.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, instead of using `.move()` to manually place your widgets, you should be using a QLayout (ex. QHBoxLayout or QVBoxLayout). This will automatically space your labels, and you can modify it by adjusting `stretch` and adding spacers (`QSpacerItem`). For more complex layouts, you can either nest multiple box layouts, or use a QGridLayout.

Now to address the scrolling:
First, you want to create your scroll area. Make this widget the central widget. Remember to set `setWidgetResizable` to `True`.

```py
scroller = QScrollArea()
scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
scroller.resize(self.width(),self.height())
scroller.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.setCentralWidget(scroller)
```

Next, create your container and add it to the scroll area. All your layout elements (labels, buttons, etc.) should be placed in this container.

```py
self.container = QWidget()
scroller.setWidget(self.container)
```

Here's the full sample program I created:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1100, 800)

        scroller = QScrollArea()
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.container = QWidget()
        scroller.setWidget(self.container)
        scroller.resize(self.width(),self.height())
        scroller.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(scroller)
        
        self.holderColumn=QVBoxLayout()
    
        txtList=["apple","banana","orange","triangle","circle","square","moon","star","sun","delta"]
        objs=list()
        for i in txtList:
            tempLabel=QLabel()
            tempLabel.setText(i)
            tempLabel.setFixedSize(300,300)
            objs.append(tempLabel)
            self.holderColumn.addWidget(tempLabel)        
        self.container.setLayout(self.holderColumn)
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: That central widget is completely useless, and the scroll area won't resize when the window is. Remove `central_widget` and just use `self.setCentralWidget(scroller)`.

Comment: @musicamante Great, thank you for the tip! And an extra thank you for not being condescending, I'm still learning in PyQt5 haha.